# how to get response in two different arrays?

Tags: ios, xml, parsing

I am doing a weather report app. So i am going to get the yahoo services API. This following code is

```
<yweather:forecast day="Thu" date="20 Dec 2012" low="70" high="89" text="Partly Cloudy" code="30"/>
<yweather:forecast day="Fri" date="21 Dec 2012" low="71" high="90" text="Partly Cloudy" code="30"/>
```

I need to get these two tags attribute values in two different arrays...

first one is one array and the second one is in another array

how can i do this help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"forecast"])
    {
        if(firstarray.count == 0)
        {
            firstarray = [attributeDict allValues];
        }
        else
        {
            secondarray = [attributeDict allValues]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its showing like this.... incompatible pointer type assigning to "NSMutableArray" _strong from NSArray

Comment: this is because u have declare NSMutableArray while [attributeDict allValues] return NSArray. use NSArray instead of NSMutableArray or use - (void)addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *)otherArray method insted of "=" operator.

Comment: If u want name and value both than u have to use NSDictionary instead of NSArray.

Comment: if u want basic of NSDictionary that go here http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Dictionary_Objects

Answer (score 0):

You could use the event-driven parser [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

And, here's how to [handle elements](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002265-BCIJFGJI) while parsing. The `attributes` dictionary parameter of the delegate method `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` will give you the element attributes which you can process as per your needs ie. add to an array.